# Handling navigation bar background gradient in iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-x

By far I handled gradient in navigation bar in the following manner_

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    let sizeLength = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height * 2
    let defaultNavigationBarFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sizeLength, height: 64)
    gradient.frame = defaultNavigationBarFrame
    gradient.colors = [UIColor(hex:"92CF1F").cgColor, UIColor(hex:"79AB1B").cgColor]

    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(self.image(fromLayer: gradient), for: .default)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = false

    if DeviceType.IS_IPAD{
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont .systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: UIFontWeightLight), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
    }
    else
    {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont .systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: UIFontWeightLight), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
    }

    UISearchBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

But Now in iPhone X I have issue due to "64" as navigation bar height for gradient as below_

[image]

Please suggest a fix for this that can be dynamically used in each case.

Answer (score 4):

Using Alisson Barauna's answer to your question, I managed to fix this issue by just updating my UINavigationBar extension to look like this:

```
extension UINavigationBar {

@objc func setGradientBackground(colors: [UIColor]) {

    var updatedFrame = bounds

    if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        if UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2436{
            updatedFrame.size.height += 44
        } else {
            updatedFrame.size.height += 20
        }
    }

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer(frame: updatedFrame, colors: colors)
    setBackgroundImage(gradientLayer.createGradientImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
}
```

By doing this the height will just be set to the larger iPhone X size (44), if the program detects that an iPhone X is being used (as the screen height is 2436).

Comment: You can use ```updatedFrame.size.height += navigationBar.frame.maxY```, in this way you don't have to check the device.

Answer (score 2):

I have checked for iPhone X mode, by the height of the screen, and then I change the gradient image generated to fill the navigation bar.
I think it's not the best workaround, but it works fine for now.

```
class func checkiPhoneModel() -> String {
    if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
        case 1136:
            return "5, 5s, 5c, se"
        case 1334:
            return "6, 6s, 7"
        case 2208:
            return "6+, 6S+, 7+"
        case 2436:
            return "X"
        default:
            return "unknown"
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

Then you can create an extension for UINavigationBar, adding a method to change the color for a gradient image:

```
extension UINavigationBar {

    func setGradientBackground(colors: [UIColor]) {

        var size:CGFloat

        if Reachability.checkiPhoneModel() == "X" {
          size = 44
        }
        else {
            size = 20
        }

        var updatedFrame = bounds
        updatedFrame.size.height += size
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer(frame: updatedFrame, colors: colors)

        setBackgroundImage(gradientLayer.creatGradientImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    }
}
```

The size var is set to 44 when is iPhone X, and other models it receives 20.

Then on your viewDidLoad, just call the method recently created:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setGradientBackground(colors: [.red, .yellow])
```

[The result is something like this. In my case, the gradient uses alpha zero at the bottom of the navigationBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1so1K.png)

Comment: Well, thats a nice way to implement it but for now I just checked 
    static let IS_IPHONE_X          = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && max(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height) == 812.0

 if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_X {
        defaultNavigationBarFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sizeLength, height: 88)
      }
      else {
        defaultNavigationBarFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sizeLength, height: 64)
      }

Answer (score 2):

How about stretching the image with `UIImage.resizableImage()` like this:
(This is nearly perfect solution)

```
open class NavigationController: UINavigationController {

    var gradientColors = [UIColor]() {
        didSet {
            updateGradient()
        }
    }

    open func updateGradient() {
        guard gradientColors.count > 1 else {
            // There has to be at least two colors to set gradient..
            return
        }
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        let defaultNavigationBarFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 64)

        gradient.frame = defaultNavigationBarFrame
        gradient.colors = gradientColors.map({ $0.cgColor })

        if let gradientImage = gradient.snapshotImage() {
            let image =  gradientImage.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 1, left: 1, bottom: 1, right: 1), resizingMode: UIImage.ResizingMode.stretch)
            UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(image, for: .default)
        }
    }
}
```

The `CALayer.snapshotImage()` implementation:

```
public extension CALayer {
    public func snapshotImage() -> UIImage? {
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: frame).image { (imageContext) in
            render(in: imageContext.cgContext)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only can you no longer assume a navigation bar height of 64, you can no longer assume a static height.

I think the simplest way of achieving what you're trying to do is to use `UINavigationController`'s `init(navigationBarClass:toolbarClass:)` method with a custom `UINavigationBar` subclass that overrides `layerClass` to specify your `CAGradientLayer` directly.

Unfortunately I don't think there's a way to "fire and forget" this with `UIAppearance`.